# Background Worker ReportProgress not firing 2

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on a Legacy app and this is driving me crazy, every example I have seen addressing this issue appears to do what I am doing but for some reason my reportProgress event refuses to fire:

```
Private _worker as BackgroundWorker

Private Sub btnEditCheckSymbol_Click (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditCheckSymbol.Click
    _worker = new BackgroundWorker()
    _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    AddHandler _worker.DoWork, AddressOf worker_DoWork
    AddHandler _worker.ProgressChanged, AddressOf worker_ProgressChanged
    AddHandler _worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf worker_RunWorkerCompleted
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync()

   'Other long running code

   If _worker.IsBusy Then
       _worker.CancelAsync()
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub worker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) _
    For i As Integer = 60 To 0 step -1
        If _worker.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
            return
        End If
        _worker.ReportProgress(i)     
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub worker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
    lbEditCheckSymbol.Invoke(
    Sub ()
        with lbEditCheckSymbol
            .Items.Clear()
            .Items.Add("Please wait for results: " + e.ProgressPercentage)
        end With
    End Sub)
    Thread.Sleep(100)
End Sub

Private Sub worker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
    with lbEditCheckSymbol
        .Items.Clear()
        If Not e.Cancelled then
            lbEditCheckSymbol.Invoke(
                Sub ()
                    with lbEditCheckSymbol
                        .Items.Add("Results should have arrived by now... um wait some more?")
                    end With
                End Sub)
        End If
    end With
End Sub
```

The DoWork is called and it burns through the loop never invoking the ProgressChanged event, I checked in the debugger and the ProgressChanged is registered.  I mostly work in C# so am I missing some VB voodoo here?

**UPDATE**
I have abandoned the use of the background worker in favor of the TPL library. Less code, easier to debug and I actually got it to work so win, win, win.

Comment: Quick tip: errors on another thread will only kill that thread and not get reported to the foreground.  Your code is going to get errors in worker_ProgressChanged() and worker_RunWorkerCompleted() when you try to access objects on the foreground thread, from the background thread.  Try setting break-points on your `with` statements and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @tgolisch Maybe I don't understand your comment, but the ProgressChanged and the WorkedCompleted methods are already on the GUI thread — it's the DoWork method that isn't.

Comment: What's going on in `'Other long running code`, which looks like it's running on the GUI thread.

Comment: @LarsTech It was a web api call that took over a minute to return.

Comment: Also, your UI will not automatically update within a loop unless you call `DoEvents()`

Comment: @tgolisch ummm, that's the point of the background worker and the invoke methods, to avoid the DoEvents hack.  Anyway, I'm not using the backgroundworker anymore so no need to debate this point.

Comment: If you have "other long-running code" being executed on the UI thread then how is your `ProgressChanged` event handler also supposed to be executed on the same UI thread simultaneously? The `ProgressChanged` event handler cannot be executed until your `Click` event handler completes. The root issue is the fact that you have long-running code executing on the UI thread.  You should be making that Web API call on a secondary thread to leave the UI thread free to do UI things, like update progress.

Answer (score 1):

If you had better error handlers around your threaded work, you would catch the access violation when your background thread tries to access objects on the foreground thread.  To reach-across threads like that, you need some delegates and use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` to call over to the right thread.

This code might not be perfect, but it should be pretty close

```
Private _worker as BackgroundWorker

Public Delegate Sub ProgressChangedDelegateType(percent As Integer)
Public Delegate Sub RunWorkerCompletedDelegateType(cancelled As Boolean)

Private progressChangedDelegate As ProgressChangedDelegateType
Private runWorkerCompletedDelegate AS RunWorkerCompletedDelegateType

Public Sub Form_Load()
    'bind your delegates in your form load event or in the class constructor
    progressChangedDelegate = AddressOf ProgressChanged
    runWorkerCompletedDelegate = AddressOf RunWorkerCompleted

    'and all of your other stuff in your form_load() event handler...
End Sub

Private Sub btnEditCheckSymbol_Click (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditCheckSymbol.Click
    _worker = new BackgroundWorker()
    _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    AddHandler _worker.DoWork, AddressOf worker_DoWork
    AddHandler _worker.ProgressChanged, AddressOf worker_ProgressChanged
    AddHandler _worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf worker_RunWorkerCompleted
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync()

   'Other long running code

   If _worker.IsBusy Then
       _worker.CancelAsync()
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub worker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) _
    For i As Integer = 60 To 0 step -1
        If _worker.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
            return
        End If
        _worker.ReportProgress(i)     
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub worker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) 
    If lbEditCheckSymbol.InvokeRequired Then
        BeginInvoke(progressChangedDelgate, {e.ProgressPercentage})
    Else
        ProgressChanged(e.ProgressPercentage)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ProgressChanged(percent As Integer)
    Try
        with lbEditCheckSymbol
            .Items.Clear()
            .Items.Add("Please wait for results: " + percent.ToString())
        end With
        DoEvents() 'forces a UI update
    Catch Ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.message) 'put a breakpoint here, just in case
    End Try
    Thread.Sleep(100)
End Sub

Private Sub worker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
    If lbEditCheckSymbol.InvokeRequired Then
        BeginInvoke(runWorkerCompletedDelegate, {e.Cancelled})
    Else
        RunWorkerCompleted(e.Cancelled)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub RunWorkerCompleted(cancelled As Boolean)
    Try
        with lbEditCheckSymbol
            .Items.Clear()
            If Not cancelled then
                .Items.Add("Results should have arrived by now... um wait some more?")
        end With
        DoEvents() 'Forces a UI update
    Catch Ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.message) 'put a breakpoint here, just in case
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure if Visual Studio treats VB differently than C#, but when using c# in debug mode with 'break on managed exceptions' all turned on, the debugger will stop anywhere there is an error.  It did not in this case.

Comment: Looks decent, but you should never hit the `InvokeRequired` section of your `worker_RunWorkerCompleted` routine because it is on the main thread. Also, that method should get rid of `DoEvents()` and `Thread.Sleep(100)`. Those just make your app slower.

Comment: Agreed. The thread.sleep and doevents are strictly aesthetic, so users can see progress updates (screen repaints) instead of the app appearing to be frozen or blinking from 1 to done.